# Syntax Error Parsing Unity YAML Scene File With Ruby & Psych

Tags: ruby, unity-game-engine, yaml

I'm trying to parse a Unity YAML scene file with Ruby and the Psych gem. The Unity file is supposedly a subset of YAML. Each Unity object is a separate YAML document. Here's a sample:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!29 &1
OcclusionCullingSettings:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  serializedVersion: 2
  m_OcclusionBakeSettings:
    smallestOccluder: 5
    smallestHole: 0.25
    backfaceThreshold: 100
  m_SceneGUID: 00000000000000000000000000000000
  m_OcclusionCullingData: {fileID: 0}
--- !u!104 &2
RenderSettings:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  serializedVersion: 9
  m_Fog: 0
  m_FogColor: {r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 0.5, a: 1}
  m_FogMode: 3
  m_FogDensity: 0.01
```

I'm parsing it with:

```rb
require 'psych'

scene = Psych.load_stream(File.read "./Scene.unity")
```

Which results in this error message:

```sh
Psych::SyntaxError ((<unknown>): found undefined tag handle while parsing a node at line 13 column 5)
```

After some investigation it appears that Psych is expecting each YAML document to have it's own TAG directive, while Unity's YAML parser must consider the directives at the beginning of the file to be global. So...

**Question 1:** Who's right? Does the scope of a TAG directive extend from declaration to the end of the file, or only to the end of the document (the next occurrance of `---`)?

I'd like to be able to parse the file without having to modify it. This leads to...

**Ouestion 2:** Is there a clean way to do this? Say a Psych option I've missed or a way to pass a block to `File.read` so that I can add TAG directives on the fly?